# When calling a function within class it errors with 'pause is required, not given' but I do not understand, why it is requiring self?

Tags: python, class

I am making a password cracking program using python 3.6 but when I call my periodic update of the possible password it is on it errors saying that "pause is required, not given".

I have tried globally defining self and removing self altogether but neither of these have worked.

```py
class Cracking(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, values, ActualPass, dataSet):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.passLen, self.cracked, self.values, self.ActualPass, self.dataSet = 1, False, values, ActualPass, dataSet

    def run(self):
        while self.cracked == False:
            startTime = time.time()
            for value in itertools.product(self.values, repeat=self.passLen):
                self.posPass = "".join(value)
                hashedPass = hashlib.sha512(self.posPass.encode()).hexdigest()
                if hashedPass == self.ActualPass:
                    endTime = time.time()
                    print("*" * 100)
                    print("Password Cracked!")
                    print(f"The password is '{self.posPass}'.")
                    print(f"Password found using the '{self.dataSet}' data set. It took {(endTime - startTime) / 60} minutes.")
                    self.cracked = True
                    exit(0)
            self.passLen += 1
        print(f"Password was not found using the '{self.dataSet}' data set.")
        exit(0)

    def ReturnPosPass(self, pause):
        while True:
            time.sleep(pause)
            print(self.posPass)


bgCrack = Cracking(values, args.ActualPass, dataSet)
bgCrack.start()
Cracking.ReturnPosPass(30)
```

I expected it to give the possible password it is checking but it just gives an error.

Comment: Did you mean `bgCrack.ReturnPosPass(30)`?

Comment: `self` is how your object is called inside itself. Do `bsCrack.ReturnPosPass(30)` - bsCrack is your `self`, you execute a method on the object